# How to find the time and step between status change

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a dataset about user status changes. and I want to find out the time it takes for the status to change, and the steps in between(number of rows).

Example data:

| user_id | Status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2001-01-01 |
| 1 | a | 2001-01-08 |
| 1 | b | 2001-01-15 |
| 1 | b | 2001-01-28 |
| 1 | a | 2001-01-31 |
| 1 | b | 2001-02-01 |
| 2 | a | 2001-01-08 |
| 2 | a | 2001-01-18 |
| 2 | a | 2001-01-28 |
| 3 | b | 2001-03-08 |
| 3 | b | 2001-03-18 |
| 3 | b | 2001-03-19 |
| 3 | a | 2001-03-20 |

Desired output:

| user_id | From | to | days in between | Steps in between |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 14 | 2 |
| 1 | b | a | 16 | 2 |
| 1 | a | b | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | b | a | 12 | 3 |

Comment: how are you creating the logic of the steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below another approach.

```sql
WITH partitions AS (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(flag) OVER w AS part FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS rn, status <> LAG(status) OVER w AS flag,
      FROM sample_data
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date)      
  ) WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date)
)
SELECT user_id,
       LAG(ANY_VALUE(status)) OVER w AS `from`,
       ANY_VALUE(status) AS `to`,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM MIN(date) - LAG(MIN(date)) OVER w) AS days_in_between,
       MIN(rn) - LAG(MIN(rn)) OVER w AS steps_in_between
  FROM partitions
 GROUP BY user_id, part
QUALIFY `from` IS NOT NULL
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY MIN(date));
```

##### Query results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  with main as (
    
    select 
      *, 
      dense_rank() over(partition by user_id order by date) as rank_,
      row_number() over(partition by user_id, status  order by date) as rank_2,
      row_number() over(partition by user_id, status  order by date) -  dense_rank() over(partition by id order by date) as diff,
      row_number() over(partition by user_id  order by date)  as row_num,
      lag(status) over(partition by user_id order by date) as prev_status, 
      concat(lag(status) over(partition by user_id order by date) , ' to ' , status) as status_change
    from table 
    ),
    
  new_rank as (
    select
      *, 
      rown_num - diff as row_num_diff, 
      min(date) over(partition by user_id, status, rown_num - diff) as min_date
    from main
    ), 
    
  prev_date as (
    select 
      *,
      lag(min_date) over(partition by user_id order by date) as prev_min_date
    from new_rank
    )
    select
      status as from, 
      prev_status as to, 
      date_diff(prev_min_date, min_date, DAY)  as days_in_between
    from prev_date 
    where status !=prev_status and prev_status is not null
```

Does this seem to work? I tried to solve this but it's very hard to solve it without a fiddle plus:

- you may remove the extra steps/ranks that I have added, I left them there so you can visually see what they are doing
- I don't get your steps logic so it is missing from the code

[image: I tried to do it manually and added on the top which functions should be used]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the step basically is how many rows the user stayed in the previous status

Comment: it seems to work on my end

Comment: @Nitekat I added a picture above, with the logic that I tried with the code. You can see from the last column the logic seems to work. Maybe you can break it into steps and check on your end ? Not sure what have you tried so far

Comment: after changing "or" to "and" in "where status !=prev_status or prev_status is not null", it works. Thank you!

Comment: somehow the days in between is not correct

Comment: Can you query step by step and share what you are coding? Plus  based on the picture are you getting the same results or following the same steps

Comment: I am using the exact code you provided, and I ran them step by step. The days_in_between shows the date diff between the last time when the status was A and the time when the status changed to B. However, it should have been from the first date when the status was A till the status changed to B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248975/discussion-between-nitekat-and-trillion).

Comment: @Nitekat did you manage to solve it? from the picture above  the prev_min_date is the lag of min_date, min_date is the date which is between each change i.e a to b and then b to a and then a to b again

Comment: If you can filter your query only for these id's, you can see which of the following parts is not matching with the excel output above and then i can look more closely. Based on what i shared it does match your expected output, i.e 14, 16, 1, 12

Comment: @Nitekat hey can you confirm till which step it is showing the same results as the picture above ? is the prev_min_date and min_date showing the same output ? as of the picture above